# how to access asmx service from HTML?

Tags: html

I have a HTML document and an .asmx service I would like to consume. The web service sends a "Hello World" message. How do I get the HTML to receive it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you  tried using "webservice.htc"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531034%28VS.85%29.aspx

OR Check out

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax/

or

http://aspalliance.com/713